# MSAL JS Directory Chooser (Switch Directory) Component for SPA

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Does Microsoft have (or is there any custom JS component that someone knows of) a directory chooser to provide "Switch Directory" functionality for an AAD secured SPA (currently using
MSAL JS https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)?

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: we implemented custom logic as described in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to switch tenants in your SPA by `msal.js`, seems there is no official demo about it. Per my understanding, if you want to do so, there will be 2 things that you should solve:

1. Your app should be able to get all tenants that the current account belongs to.
2. The public client Azure AD App should be a [multi-tenant one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) so that users could be able to log in to different tenants seamlessly.

For point 1, we can use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) to get all user tenants. This API belongs to Azure management rest API, so your public client Azure AD App should be granted with permission below so that users logged in could call this API to get all tenants:

[image]

I write a simple demo by msal.js for you that could meet your requirement I think, just try the HTML page code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title>Azure AD test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.4.4/js/msal.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div >
                    
        <button id="SignIn" onclick="signIn()">Sign in</button><br/>
        <div id="WelcomeMessage"/><br/>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    var clientAppID = "<multi tenant public client Azure ad app id>"
    var tenantID = "<tenant ID for default login >"
    
    var demoScops = {
         scopes:["https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation"]
    }

    var msalConfig = {
             auth: {
                 clientId: clientAppID,
                 authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID
            },
             cache: {
                 cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                 storeAuthStateInCookie: true
            }
    };
     

    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);
             
    
    function signIn() {
     
         myMSALObj.loginPopup(demoScops).then(function (loginResponse) {
            console.log(loginResponse);
            initPage();
             
         }).catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
     }
     
    function initPage(){
        showWelcomeMessage();
        getAllTenants();
        
     }
     

     
     function showWelcomeMessage() {
             
         var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
         divWelcome.innerHTML = 'welcome! ' + myMSALObj.account.userName + '</br>';
         var loginbutton = document.getElementById('SignIn');
         loginbutton.innerHTML = 'sign out';
         loginbutton.setAttribute('onclick', 'signOut();');
     }
     
     function getAllTenants(){
         myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(demoScops).then(function (tokenResponse) {
         
             var accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
             $.ajax({
                 url: "https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01",
                 type: "GET",
                 async: false,
                 beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ accessToken);},
                 success: function(data) { 
                    var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
                    divWelcome.innerHTML += "  your current tenant: "+ myMSALObj.account.idToken.tid +", all your tenants :</br>"
                    data.value.forEach(item=>{
                        var tentantItem  = "<div id='"+item.tenantId+"' style='border: 2px solid grey; margin:5px; width:500px' onclick='switchTenant(this)' > name :"+item.displayName+ "     Tenant  ID:"+ item.tenantId +"</div>" 
                        divWelcome.innerHTML += tentantItem;
                    })
                 }
              });
              
              
         }).catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
              })
        }     
     
     function switchTenant(obj){

        var msalConfig = {
                 auth: {
                     clientId: clientAppID,
                     authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + $(obj).attr('id')
                },
                 cache: {
                     cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                     storeAuthStateInCookie: true
                }
    };
     
    
    
    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);
    
     myMSALObj.loginPopup(demoScops).then(function (loginResponse) {
            console.log(loginResponse);
            location.reload();
             
         }).catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
    
    
    }
     
     
     function authRedirectCallBack(error, response) {
         if (error) {
             console.log(error);
         }
     }
     
     function requiresInteraction(errorCode) {
         if (!errorCode || !errorCode.length) {
             return false;
         }
         return errorCode === "consent_required" ||
             errorCode === "interaction_required" ||
             errorCode === "login_required";
     }
     

     var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
     var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
     var msie11 = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
     var msedge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
     var isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
     var isEdge = msedge > 0;

     var loginType = isIE ? "REDIRECT" : "POPUP";
     
     if (loginType === 'POPUP') {
          if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
              initPage()
          }
     }
     else if (loginType === 'REDIRECT') {
         document.getElementById("SignIn").onclick = function () {
              myMSALObj.loginRedirect(requestObj);
         };
         if (myMSALObj.getAccount() && !myMSALObj.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {
              initPage()
          }
     } else {
         console.error('Please set a valid login type');
     }
     
     

      function signOut() {
          window.localStorage.clear();
          myMSALObj.logout();
      }
    
</script>

</html>
```

**Result:**

Once I login , it will display my current tenant id and all my tenants:
[image]

Once I click a tenant item, a login window prompts out and relod the page after successful login:

[image]

finally:

[image]